# Is my battery completely dead?

Tags: laptop, battery, battery-life

I left my Asus Vivobook Pro 15 not plugged in overnight to download a file. I didn't expect the battery to run out but it did.

Now, apparently, it won't charge and my laptop shows no signs of life even though yesterday everything was perfectly fine. as laptop.

I've been using the laptop for less than a year.

Comment: Asus usually has a battery warranty of 12 months. The rest of the laptop could have 1-2 years more. It depends on your country.

Comment: You should seek warranty repair. Even if the warranty is technically “expired” something like this sounds like a defect. Contact Asus ASAP and get the process started.

Comment: Do leave it charging for a few hours just in case it wants to be fully charged before it turns on.

Answer (score 2):

This event is not normal for a new laptop.

A battery being completely discharged does not mean that
it cannot be recharged afterward. In addition, your laptop
perhaps cannot function without a working battery.

If the laptop is still under warranty, I would demand to
replace the battery, or even replace/return the entire
laptop if you're unsure that the problem is only with
the battery.